Child process detects STDOUT redirection on Windows
I want to make a wrapper for a Windows console utility that would add some keybindings and remember history. The problem I'm running into is that child process detects that its output is being redirected and behaves differently from how it would behave without the wrapper. Is there a way I can trick the child process into thinking its output is not being redirected? I am using anonymous pipes for redirecting the output.
I tried adding STARTF_USESIZE and STARTF_USEPOSITION flags to STARTUPINFOW struct and setting dwXSize/dwYSize, but that didn't make any difference.
